# How to implement that at least/at most n elements in a list are true?

Tags: prolog

In preparation for an exam, we had a practice task where we were told to implement two predicates in prolog that get two inputs (a natural number n and a list).

When atLeast/atMost n elements from the list are true, then the predicate should have true as an output; otherwise it should be false. In addition, we were told that we can only use cuts, negation and the predef arithmetic predicates.

To be honest, I struggle with finding a solution and have no idea how to start on that problem. It would be really nice if someone could help and explain to me how I to solve it

Comment: Start by thinking about it carefully and trying something out. Right now you are "I've tried nothing and I am all out of ideas" (which btw is a joke)

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem like it should be more complicated than counting the number of true values and comparing it to the supplied N.

A common pattern in Prolog programming is the use of quasi-private *helper predicates* that do the actual work, and carry extra variables that maintain the state necessary to accomplish the actual computation.

So, to count the number of `true` values in the list, is easy. We create a helper predicate that does the actual counting. We can call it `truthy( List, Accumulator, Count )`. Note that it carries an extra variable (`Accumulator`) that builds up the count as we go.

```
truthy( []        , N , N ) .  % if the list is exhausted, we're done. Unify the accumulator and the count.
truthy( [true|Xs] , T , N ) :- % Otherwise, if the head of the list is true,
  T1 is T+1,                   % - increment the count,
  !,                           % - eliminate the choice point, and
  truthy( Xs, T1, N ).         % - recurse down
truthy( [_|Xs]    , T , N ) :- % Finally, All that over than truth is false, by definition, so...
  truthy( Xs, T,  N )          % - just recurse down.
  .                            % Easy!
```

Once you have that, then it's a matter of evaluating it, and comparing that with the result:

```
at_least(Xs,N) :-  % To see if the list has at least N true items...
  truthy(Xs,0,T) , % - call the helper, seeding the accumulator with zero, and
  T >= N .         % - compare that to the supplied value of N.
```

Putting it all together you get:

```
at_least(Xs,N) :- truthy(Xs,0,Ts), Ts >= N.

truthy( []        , N , N ).
truthy( [true|Xs] , T , N ) :- T1 is T+1, !, truthy( Xs, T1, N ).
truthy( [_|Xs]    , T , N ) :-               truthy( Xs, T,  N ).
```

Answer (score -1):

Approach 1: run down the list, pending all the counting until later, get to the end, an empty list with an anchor count of 0 truths in it. Then pull back up adding `+1` each time there was a truth passed on the way down.

```
atLeast([], 0).

atLeast([L|Ls], N) :-
    L,
    atLeast(Ls, Nless1),
    N is Nless1 + 1.

atLeast([L|Ls], N) :-
    not(L),
    atLeast(Ls, N).
```

Benefit: shorter code, can also work backwards and given a list of truths tell you the count.

Cost: builds up a stack of pending additions as long as the list, which costs runtime and memory.

---

Approach 2: take the list Ls, and cutoff N, and set a counter at 0. You will count, and at the end, compare the count to N.

```
atLeast(Ls, N) :-
    atLeast(Ls, N, 0).
```

At the end which is an empty list, compare:

```
atLeast([], N, Counter) :-
    Counter >= N.
```

In the middle, a case for increasing the counter when there's a true at the head of the list:

```
atLeast([L|Ls], N, Counter) :-
    L,
    Counter2 is Counter+1,
    atLeast(Ls, N, Counter2).
```

and a case for not increasing the counter when there's not a true at the head of the list:

```
atLeast([L|Ls], N, Counter) :-
    not(L),
    atLeast(Ls, N, Counter).
```

and all of them together handle:

- starting a counter.
- counting trues.
- recursing to the end of the list.
- checking the counter value at the end of the list against the given N.

e.g.

```
?- atLeast([false, true, true, false, true], 3).
true
```

and

```
?- atLeast([4>5, integer(88), atom(a), integer(9.7), 6>2 ], 3).
true
```

Benefits: doesn't build up a stack of pending additions, so uses less memory and runs faster.

Costs: can't work backwards.

---

Nitpicking: if you can only define predicates and use cuts, negation and arithmetic, I don't think you can solve it. You need [`,/2`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=,/2) ("conjunction", the comma which ANDs Prolog terms together), at least.